# How to sign snaps without pushing or pushing it to snap store?

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, signature

I am creating a snap for my software but until now I've been using `--devmode` or `--dangerous` flag to snap install. Now, I would like to sign it, but I can't find something like step-by-step or tutorial to do that apart of publishing and pushing my work.

Is it possible to sign a snap without publishing or pushing it to the snap storage? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Only snaps which are uploaded to the store will be signed by the store.